# SMTPResponseException smtplib.SMTPResponseException: (334, b'UGFzc3dvcmQ6')

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, sendmail, smtplib

I am creating a contact form so that if the user have anything to say, they will submit a form to the admin using their google email.

I use Flask and smtplib to apply.

Here is my code:

```
MAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get("EMAIL_KEY")
MAIL_APP_PW = os.environ.get("PASSWORD_KEY")

@app.route("/contact", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def contact():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.form
        send_email(data["name"], data["email"], data["phone"], data["message"])
        return render_template("contact.html", msg_sent=True, current_user=current_user)
    return render_template("contact.html", msg_sent=False, current_user=current_user)


def send_email(name, email, phone, message):
    email_message = f"Subject:New Message\n\nName: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nPhone: {phone}\nMessage:{message}"
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=MAIL_ADDRESS, password=MAIL_APP_PW)
        connection.sendmail(from_addr=email, to_addrs=MAIL_ADDRESS, msg=email_message)
```

I already created an app password in my Gmail and also used the environment variables.
Am I missing something or there is something in my codde that is not correct?

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daotronggiabao/Downloads/day-71-starting-files-blog-for-deployment/main.py", line 286, in send_email
    connection.login(user=MAIL_ADDRESS, password=MAIL_APP_PW)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 652, in auth
    authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I appreciate any suggestion.